# Proper header file pathing when referencing from multiple headers

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I have a software package with many headers that are under a folder and reference each other.

(inside header 1)
#include "math/header2.h"

(inside header 2)
#include "math/header1.h"

The main.c includes both .. and if I set gcc -I path_to_math .. main can find all headers.

The problem is each header cannot find the other no mater what I do.

Seem as if header1 which is already in the math folder .. wants to see a math folder under the math folder and visa versa.

I get file not found for both no matter what I try?

Is this a bad practice?

What is the way to fix this?

Comment: `gcc -I path_to_math_parent` or edit the headers if they are under your control.

Comment: with the headers including each other, sounds ripe for a circular dependency. Are you using `#include` guards?

Comment: Yes the author used include guards.

Comment: If you use I- path_to_math_parent .. then do #include "math/header.h" .. or any further subfolders .. will this work?

Comment: finally figured it out .. I needed to add the top "src" folder to the includes search path.